# CSS Menu Dropdown IE7 float left

Tags: css, menu

I made a nice menu, and I also wrote a new design for only IE. In IE7 the text next to image doesn`t go next to it. It goes to next line. Anybody knows how can I fix it ?

http://tinyurl.com/6yzd2jc

Comment: Sorry if this isn't really constructive, but I feel like you should be able to make a similar menu without resorting to seperate versions for seperate browsers.  What is your reasoning behind this choice?

Comment: if anyone wants to play with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/MNwD3/

Comment: It is not a valid markup to have a block level element inside an inline element, You have div inside an a tag, further there is some redundant CSS, div is  a block level element by default, and there is no need to specify it again through CSS. You may look here as well:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-a-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: I am with @ZachL. here, this menu could easily be made cross-browser

Comment: @refhat - while you're correct with regard to xhtml (which the OP is specifying in his doctype), in HTML5 it is perfectly valid to have a `<div>` inside an `<a>` tag (one is expected to style the `<a>` as something other than `inline` though). Most browsers are quite happy with it regardless of the doctype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply the `background-image` to the anchor tag.

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/MNwD3/38/)

So replace:

```
ul ul a div {float:left;display:block;width:7px;height:10px;background-color:transparent;padding:0;margin:0 5px 0 0;position:relative;top:3px;}
ul ul a:hover div {display:block;background-image:url(http://ctuchicago.squarespace.com/storage/jquery/dot.png);width:7px;height:10px;}
```

With:

```
ul ul a:hover {background:transparent url(http://ctuchicago.squarespace.com/storage/jquery/dot.png) no-repeat left center;}
```

Also increase the `<a>` left padding (from `padding:3px 16px 3px 4px;` to `padding:3px 16px 3px 14px;`)

```
ul ul li a {
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #FFF;
    padding:3px 16px 3px 14px;
}
```

and remove the empty `<div>`s nested in the anchors

Answer (score 0):

Why You are Using `div` inside `a` tag ?

remove `div` from `a` tag and apply CSS Style `background-image` in `a` tag

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/MNwD3/40/